# ios9, ALAsset.thumbnail.size is {75,75}?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alasset

In iOS 9, I selected a photo from an album. After obtaining the ALAsset,
I called the "thumbnail" to get a thumbnail and display it but photos are  blurred.

In iOS 8, `ALAsset.thumbnail` size are `150 * 150`, but in iOS 9 its `75 * 75`

This is my code:

```
self.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.asset.thumbnail];
//self.image.size is 75*75     in ios9
//self.image.size is 150*150     in ios8
```

How can I solve this problem?

If I use:

```
[self.asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]
```

Then I get poor efficiency.

Comment: Yes, you should use `Photos` framework to refactor it. Example: [Example app using Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I bumped into this too and submitted it as a bug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also had this problem and solved it by using **`asset.aspectRatioThumbnail`**

```
    UIImageView *imageView;
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem. ALAsset available in iOS 4.0 and later deprecated in iOS 9.0.   You can use PHAsset instead in iOS9.